# PHP parse error on Laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel

After installing Laravel and updating Composer, I get a weird PHP syntax error in my PHP error logs:

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '.' in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/scandipage/public/index.php on line 21

Line 21 of index.php:

```
require __DIR__.’/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

Already checked PHP version on my Mac (PHP 5.5.10 (cli) (built: Apr 10 2014 17:49:22) ).
What else could be the reason for this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single quote doesn't look right (note the difference at the first opening quote). Try replace line 21 with this:

```
require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';
```

It feels a little uncomfortable to me that a default file from Laravel does this. You may want to reclone your project again.

Comment: Wow. How did I miss that? D: Totally going to re-clone the whole project.